# created a react app when using internet explorer pop up modal breaks chrome, firefox or safari it works fine any advice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I built an app using react.js it looks good but after i click on a button for the modal window to pop up it breaks.  i even looked up the create react support website and found out that  react-app-polyfill. can make it work... i did that and it didnt work .

i did the react-app-polyfill and still my pop up modal window still breaks.

after console.log no errors came up

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

    class Modal extends Component {



  render() {
    //console.log(this.props.itemInfo)
    // Render nothing if the "show" prop is false
    if (!this.props.show) {
      return null;
    }

    // The gray background
    const backdropStyle = {
      position: 'fixed',
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'hsl(0, 100%, 30%)',
      padding: 50
    };

    // The modal "window"
    const modalStyle = {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      margin: '25px auto',
      padding: 30,
      display: "flex",
      height: "auto",
      width: "auto",
      flexWrap: "wrap",
      textAlign: "center",
      overflow: "auto",

    };

    const productImg = {
      maxWidth: "600px"
    }

    const cardHeader = {
      marginBottom: "20px"
    }
    const cardBody = {
      height: "calc(100vh - 200px)",
      overflow: "auto"
    }

    return (
      <div className="backdrop" style={backdropStyle}>
        <div className="modal" style={modalStyle}>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
              <div className="card">
                <h6 className="card-header" style={cardHeader}>Item # 
    {this.props.itemInfo.item_no} - {this.props.itemInfo.item}</h6>
                <div className="card-body" style={cardBody}>

                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12"><img src= . 
    {this.props.itemInfo.image} alt="" style={productImg}></img></div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="row justify-content-center mt-3">
                    <div className="col-10" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ 
        __html: this.props.itemInfo.description }} />
                  </div>

                  <div className="row justify-content-center mt-3">
                    <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" 
        onClick={this.props.onClose}>Close</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
      }

   Modal.propTypes = {
     onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    show: PropTypes.bool
  };

    export default Modal;
```

Comment: What error? Can you provide more details?

Comment: @valerii i didnt get any errors.   when ever i open up my pop up model window it breaks .